# Checking for prime number in ruby

Tags: ruby, square-root

I am trying to write a method that takes a number and checks if its a prime number. After doing some research a fast way to check is to divide the number by every number between 2 and sqrt(number we are checking). I want my method to return true if it is a prime number and false if it isn't.

So I tried to write code that made logical sense to me but I am getting an error. Here's what I have written:

```
def PrimeTime(num)
    counter = 2
    while counter <= Math.sqrt(num).ceil
        (counter == Math.sqrt(num).ceil) ? "false"
        (num % counter == 0) ? "true" : counter += 1
    end
end
```

This gives me

```
(eval):429: (eval):429: compile error (SyntaxError)
(eval):422: syntax error, unexpected '\n'
```

Rewritten code

```
def prime?(num)
    (2..Math.sqrt(num).ceil).to_a.each do |number|
        if num % number == 0
            return false
        else
            return true
        end
    end
end
```

FYI, this is not homework. I am going through coderbyte problems. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proximate issue you are facing is, this is not valid Ruby: `(counter == Math.sqrt(num).ceil) ? "false"`

`?`, as an operator, is a part of the trinary operator `... ? ... : ...`, and always comes in pair with a `:`, as you write in your next line. Then again, overuse of trinary operator is also not good. You also have a problem with control flow: after evaluating `"true"`, the loop will continue, `counter` won't change, and you got an infinite loop.

I suggest you work out what the algorithm should be. Write it in English, if necessary. Then make sure you convert it to Ruby correctly.

Also, Ruby methods should be in snake case (lowercase with underscores between words), so `PrimeTime` is not a good name. I suggest `prime?` (as question marks are also allowed in identifiers) if you will be returning a boolean value (`true` or `false`). If you are returning a string (as you seem to be trying to do), try `check_for_primality` or something similar (without the question mark).

Also... if remainder is zero, the number is *not* prime. I think you have your tests switched around.

If you are still stumped:

> def prime?(num); (2..Math.sqrt(num)).each do |counter|; if (num % counter == 0); return false end end; true; end

**EDIT** On rewritten code: `break & return false` doesn't do what you want. They are both control statements; if you `break`, `return` won't happen. Even if it did, if the break wasn't there, it would have been better to write `and`, or at least `&&`, not `&` (binary and).

Your logic is still wrong though: `PrimeTime(16)` is `true`, for example, is not really what I'd expect from a primality testing function.

Comment: "I suggest you work out what the algorithm should be. Write it in English, if necessary. Then make sure you convert it to Ruby correctly" -- [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/), for example. Read [the Rpec Book](http://www.amazon.com/RSpec-Book-Behaviour-Development-Cucumber/dp/1934356379/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1410408767&sr=1-1&keywords=the+rspec+book)

Comment: @J-Dizzle: I think that's a bit too high level for someone struggling with syntax and basic flow control. Best intro to Ruby+TDD I have seen is [RubyKoans](http://rubykoans.com/).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your making this way more complicated than it should be. Here's the code that I would advise using.

```
require 'prime'

puts 2.prime?
```

Its that simple. And if you want to make your own method

```
require 'prime'

def prime?(num)
    num.prime?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby comes with predefined classes such as `Prime`. All you have to do is to require that class into your project.

```
require 'prime'
```

Than, you can use some of the `Prime methods` such as **first** to get first x prime elements:

```
Prime.first(5) # Ret => [2, 3, 5, 6, 11]
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
Prime.each(100) do |prime|
  p prime # Ret => [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ..., 97]
end
```

I hope this may helpful to you.. via miksiii

Comment: I get that. I just wanted to build my own method for practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without Math.sqrt this way:

```
def is_prime?(number)
  (2..number-1).each {|n| return false if number <= 1 || number % n == 0}
  return true
end
```